Multisite permalink issue
I have a WP multisite on AWS running a nginx-based server. It has autoscaling enabled as well. For some reason, and for only some pages (mostly custom post types), after every deployment these CPT's will give 404s.
Then I need to manually go to the settings and go to permalinks and just resave the permalink structure to trigger rewrite rule flush.
Now, because we are deploying the site using codedeploy, I added a wpcli script that will do that for me
exec("~/bin/wp site list --json --field=url", $siteOuput, $return);

$siteList = json_decode($siteOuput[0], true);

foreach($siteList as $siteUrl) {
    exec("~/bin/wp rewrite flush --url=$siteUrl", $permalinkOutput, $return);
}

This seemingly works (we have logging where it says that the permalink flush was successful for sites). However, this doesn't seem to be the case. When I go to a CPT, it will throw 404 and I need to manually go to the settings and resave permalinks.
The rewrite rules are set in the database so this is super confusing. Also, flushing permalinks from wpcli obviously is not working, so is there a difference between web and cli context here?
I did try to trigger a call to a rest route that had the logic for flushing permalinks, but that also didn't work (again here I suspected this wouldn't work from the rest API context).
Does anybody have any idea what could be the issue and how to fix this? The main issue is that when an autoscaling event happens, permalinks go kaput :S

I wonder if it's making an nginx config change too, but then AFAIK WordPress only makes .htaccess edits out of the box. Do you have an nginx support plugin? Can you compare the config (or the filesystem in general) on a working instance against a broken one? I can't see why things wouldn't work from REST though, unless there's some extra admin-site-only logic somewhere.

That said I don't think the permalink config varies by CPT type :-/

My hunch is that it's a caching fault. We do have wp redis as well, and maybe there could be a rewrite mismatch or something. So far it affects only CPTs

So the problem was in the custom rest route which had the call to flush_rewrite_rules() which (as far as I can see) resetted the permalinks to default somehow and messed up the permalink structure.
Once we removed all the calls to the custom route no 404 happened.
